# How to update Language pack in expo?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I am using `i18n` for language translation in my add. It is now static `en.json` file.
I'd like to set up multiple `languages` dynamically for my device environment, which will download through `API` and it will save on `device`.